# Implementing my own GNU stricmp, wcsicmp etc for wchar* stuff

Tags: c++

Ok.  I need to implement methods like these.  Is there a way to view the source code online for methods like these, so I can just add them into my own .h and .cpp files? will this work and where can I see the source.

Comment: If you'd copy the code, you must of course respect the license. These functions come from `glibc`, so it's LGPL.

Comment: @MSalters There are many more C libraries than glibc, although glibc is probably the biggest outside the Windows and Mac world, and one of the few that is free software. Another open source C library is [newlib](http://sourceware.org/newlib/).

Comment: @Joachim: The title specifically mentions **GNU** `stricmp`. GNU software is usually GPL or LGPL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These functions are part of glibc,
you can find it here http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/ .
You can download release version via ftp or get current version
via git (you can find links on html url above), as I know there is no access to code via web to separate files,
but may be, may be codesearch http://www.google.com/codesearch, can show them, but I never try.